# Paperclip association question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have two model
User and UserAgent
User has one UserAgent & UserAgent belongs to User
And UserAgent using Paperclip to upload file to server
Using this


`has_attached_file :agreement,

  :path => "#{Rails.root}/public/upload/new_agreements/:id/:basename.:extension"`

This working fine.It is creating folders needed to upload the file.

But i need to create the folder like this

`:path => "#{Rails.root}/public/upload/new_agreements/User:id/:basename.:extension"`


That means I need to upload the file according to the User.id but not UserAgent.Id
Is there any way? You can ask questions if u don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that. I haven't test it, but you can modify it:

```
class UserAgent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file, 
                    :path => lambda{ |a| "#{Rails.root}/public/upload/new_agreements/#{a.instance.user.id}/:id/:basename.:extension" }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.But It gives the same result.And whether i need to put this lines in my User.rb file? Now it is in useragent.rb(model) file.Because I want to save the file details in user_agent database table.

Comment: I've aI've updated my answer, and you should add this into your `UserAgent` model

Comment: Lots of thanks Mr fl00r,It is worked for me.And this is the reason why I love opensource and stackoverflow :)